# cassandra does not start when try to start it as a service

Tags: cassandra, server, redhat, nosql

i installed cassandra in RHEL6 system using yum manager. also configured the yaml file according to the datastax guidelines. but when i try to start as a service it gives following INFO in the log file.but cassandra server does not start.

```
INFO  [STREAM-INIT-/10.76.10.82:59899] 2015-10-20 01:07:33,523 StreamResultFuture.java:116 - [Stream #da0ad600-76f0-11e5-8d1d-1f91bf0f84ef, ID#0] Received streaming plan for Bootstrap
INFO  [STREAM-INIT-/10.76.10.82:59900] 2015-10-20 01:07:33,546 StreamResultFuture.java:116 - [Stream #da0ad600-76f0-11e5-8d1d-1f91bf0f84ef, ID#0] Received streaming plan for Bootstrap
INFO  [STREAM-IN-/10.76.10.82] 2015-10-20 01:07:33,651 StreamResultFuture.java:180 - [Stream #da0ad600-76f0-11e5-8d1d-1f91bf0f84ef] Session with /10.76.10.82 is complete
INFO  [STREAM-IN-/10.76.10.82] 2015-10-20 01:07:33,652 StreamResultFuture.java:212 - [Stream #da0ad600-76f0-11e5-8d1d-1f91bf0f84ef] All sessions completed
INFO  [StorageServiceShutdownHook] 2015-10-20 01:28:50,930 ThriftServer.java:142 - Stop listening to thrift clients
INFO  [StorageServiceShutdownHook] 2015-10-20 01:28:50,978 Server.java:214 - Stop listening for CQL clients
INFO  [StorageServiceShutdownHook] 2015-10-20 01:28:50,980 Gossiper.java:1442 - Announcing shutdown
INFO  [StorageServiceShutdownHook] 2015-10-20 01:28:50,983 StorageService.java:1698 - Node /10.76.10.78 state jump to normal
INFO  [StorageServiceShutdownHook] 2015-10-20 01:28:53,014 MessagingService.java:735 - Waiting for messaging service to quiesce
INFO  [ACCEPT-/10.76.10.78] 2015-10-20 01:28:53,016 MessagingService.java:1011 - MessagingService has terminated the accept() thread
```

Comment: Can you change log levele to DEBUG/TRACE and see why MessagingService is being terminated? is this a single node installation?

Comment: Can you share some for info like YAML configuration, also check if its getting killed due to memory limitation.

Comment: This is an five node cluster installed on a cloud environment. all the machines runs on redhat linux 6 .i also checked if there is any memory limitation